# which function is there in android for the following java function--statement = database.createStatement(sqlStatement);?

Tags: android

```
public void execute(String sqlStatement) throws DBException {
    Statement statement;

    try {
        statement = database.createStatement(sqlStatement);
        statement.prepare();
        statement.execute();
        statement.close();
    } catch (DatabaseException databaseException) {
        throw new DBException(Class.class.getName(), "execute", databaseException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This is the function in java that i have to implement in android. In android how can i use the createstatement(), statement.prepare() and statement.execute() functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**execSQL**" if you want to execute any query.

e.g:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableName(field1, field2)" + " Values('"
        + value1 + "', '" + value2 + "');");
```

if you want to fetch data from data base then use **Cursor**.

e.g:

```
Cursor c = null;
c = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);

while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String fname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field1"));
    String lname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field2"));
}
```